# Fetching data from database using ajax and php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Below filmdetails.php file i want to call on href click, how i can incorporate the same using ajax for mobile app. i mean when i click on link filmdetails.php?id=12 then below code will fetch the 12 id having data associated with it such as name and year of the film

I want to process this using ajax. please guide

```
<?php

include('connection.php');

$filmId = $_GET['filmId'];

$sql ="SELECT * FROM films where filmId ='$filmId'";
mysqli_query("SET NAMES utf8");
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $id = $row['filmId'];
    $name = $row['filmName'];
    $year = $row['filmYear'];

    echo "$name, $year";
}

mysql_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: Sidenote: You're mixing an `mysql_` function using `mysql_free_result` along with `mysqli_`. Those do not intermix with each other. Use `mysqli_free_result` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**suppose your a tag has id named getcountry, than use**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#getcountry').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "filmdetails.php",
            data: { filmId: <?php echo $_GET['filmId']; ?> }
        }).done(function( msg ) {
            alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: i tried the same but not working, i also want on href bit complicated for me as not comfortable in js

Answer (score 1):

I think This trick will be work.

```
<a href="filmdetails.php?foo_id=' . $film_id . '" class="clickMe">
<span id="results"></span>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('a.clickMe').click(function(e){
   // Stop default click action in browser
   e.preventDefault();

   // Make ajax call
   $.ajax($(e.target).attr("href"), {
     cache:false,
     success:function(data){
         $("#results").html(data);
     }
   });
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Send the `filmId` via your AJAX request.

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "filmdetails.php",
    data: { filmId: <?php echo $_GET['filmId']; ?> }
}).done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

You will see your data in an alert. You can put this data in document using jQuery's `.html()` method.

Comment: i want to fetch above php data on href, please let me know how i can do here...as i am newbe in ajax .